# SQL User Bulk Removal

Tags: sql

After I removed an AD Group from the general security area, it's still mapped to about 18 Databases (This is a QA box) how can I get rid of all the account without having to go through each DB one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can script it out similar to this:

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'USERNAME') DROP USER [USERNAME]"
GO
```

I've only used it for individual users, not for groups, but it should work.